# ANTLR parser rule to match: x and/or y and/or z in any order

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Using ANTLR, is there a way to write a parser rule so that it can express: x and/or y and/or z in any order without writing Java. For example it should match: "x y", "y z", and "x y z" but not "x x y". The best I can think of is is the rule below but then I would need to check in the tree walker for "x x y".

```
rule: ( x | y | z )* ;
```

Answer (score 3):

While you *can* do something akin to:

```
rule: x
    | y
    | z
    | x y
    | y x
    | x z
    | z x
    | y z
    | z y
    | x y z
    | x z y
    | y x z
    | y z x
    | z x y
    | z y x;
```

or (a little less absurd):

```
rule: x? y? z?
    | x? z? y?
    | y? x? z?
    | y? z? x?
    | z? x? y?
    | z? y? x?
    ;
```

I'd suspect that you're example is much simpler than your real application, and this approach would become way too tedious (It's already getting absurd).

You could also look into something using semantic predicates, but that will lock your grammar to a particular target language.  (It'll also complicate your grammar.)

In general, I find that ANTLR users (parser writers in general), often try too hard to encode "all the rules" into the grammar.

This seems like it would be nice, but it can lead to a lot of complexity in the grammar, and to "less than optimal" error messages (since they're coming from the parser (ANTLR) itself).

I think you'll find that it's better to keep a rule like you have which will create a ParseTree that accurately represents the right way to interpret (a.k.a. "parse") the input.  Then you consider a rule like this to be a Semantic concern (as opposed to a Syntactic concern (the domain of the parser).

That means that you would write something like a validation Listener that would run against your parse tree, and you can check for use of the same child rule more than once.  If you encounter it, you can then craft a very specific error message that is more useful to the end user.

Comment: Thx Mike. Sadly you're right, there are three instances where I would like to use 'the trick' with 3, 4 and 7 variables respectively so the combinatorics approach doesn't quite do it! I did originally planned to handle the problem outside of the parser but it that's turning out to be quite difficult too  - I have 5 listeners (!) at the moment so I'm looking to push back as much as I can into the parser.

Comment: Maybe somebody will have an idea that escapes me at this time, but I'd suggest that having multiple listeners is not that bad and is more "the ANTLR way".  I've always found that I needed a validation listener for semantic error checking anyway.  If one of the existing listeners is doing validation, that I'd add to that.  Depending on your use case, I don't know that 5 listeners is a "bad thing" especially if it helps with code clarity giving separation of concerns.  (TBC)

Comment: I find that I'll sometimes leave certain rules out of the grammar deliberately as long as the grammar can give me a ParseTree that is the correct interpretation of the input.  I can then provide better error messages than I can expect ANTLR to generate just looking at grammar rules.  (another trick is to actually put rules for known problem constructs, just so you can recognize them and give a more meaningful error message.)

Comment: I've added an answer below with the best I can come up with and it looks better than I thought it would. I can reuse the booleans in the different rules and I don't intend to use it other than in Java...

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come up with is...

```
grammar Sandbox;

@members {
    boolean a, b, c;
}

start: ( 'test' test )+ EOF ;

test:
    {a=b=c=true;}   // Reset
    (   {a}? a {a=false;}
    |   {b}? b {b=false;}
    |   {c}? c {c=false;}
    )* ;

a: 'a';
b: 'b';
c: 'c';

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

And the test driver...

```
package sandbox;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    private Main() {
        System.out.println("Should be OK...");
        test("test a b c test c test c b a test c");
        System.out.println("Should fail...");
        test("test c a a");
    }

    private void test(String toTest) {
        final CharStream cs = CharStreams.fromString(toTest);
        final SandboxLexer lexer = new SandboxLexer(cs);
        final CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        final SandboxParser parser = new SandboxParser(tokens);
        parser.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s the semantic predicate solution I made reference to. (And didn’t bother to write :) ). And, yeah, it’s not *quite* as ugly as I imagined